# Does Heart Rate Services/Characteristics Assigned Number in BLE Devices is different for each manufacturer/Brand?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, fitbit, heartrate, react-native-ble-plx

I have been working on a Mobile application in react-native which connects to any SmartWatch(fitbit/Samsung) or any sensors which advertise the heart rate with their services and characteristics. Currently i'm holding a Fitbit Versa Lite Smart Watch which has a heart rate sensor. I was able to connect to the Fitbit and reading all its services and characteristics. But i wasn't able to find any particular assigned number related to heart rate services or its characteristics. I'm assuming almost all the watches and the BLe sensor which advertise the Heart Rate measurements uses

Services

```
Heart Rate  org.bluetooth.service.heart_rate    0x180D  GSS
```

Characteristics

```
Heart Rate Measurement  org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement 0x2A37  GSS.
```

I got the above information from the below links.

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/

Does FitBit Uses different Assigned Numbers for their Heart Rate Sensor Services and characteristics. If it does what are the Assigned Number?

Comment: Yes it is likely that it is using a different custom UUID. I have a Xiaomi Mi Band and it uses a different UUID as well. The difference being is that when you use the custom 0x180D UUID, it means that any app can read the HRM data because of compatibility. However, this is also not always desirable + is more expensive to qualify from FitBit/Xiaomi's end + is limiting in terms of what kind of data you can send over the air.

Comment: @YoussifSaeed Thank you for responding. So you meant to say only few of the features of the smart watch can be shared over air, rest of them can only be accessed by SDK. That makes sense. In Fitbit versa Lite watch there are some custom services provided, i'm guessing one of them related to heart rate. I have dropped the same question in FitBit SDK Community waiting for them to acknowledge the same.

Comment: @YoussifSaeed Can u please help me how to get heart rate from Fitbit Versa using Web Bluetooth Api using navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice. Can u please help me

Comment: @Piyush Aggarwal unfortunately I don't have any experience with React Native, Web Bluetooth Api, and I don't have a FitBit, so unfortunately I don't think I can help. Maybe it is best to contact FitBit about accessing this information.